# How to match rows in excel and append columns for adding data

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have sheets of monthly data for all our products:

Sheet 1 - January:

```
Product Name  Total Items  Total Orders
Product1      3            5
Product2      5            5
Product3      2            1
```

Sheet 2 - February:

```
Product Name  Total Items  Total Orders
Product1      1            1
Product2      2            1
Product4      4            4
Product5      3            2
```

How do I combine these into one sheet so that I can have an output like:

```
Product Name  Jan Items  Jan Orders Feb Items Feb Orders
Product1      3          5           1          1
Product2      5          5           2          1
Product3      2          1 
Product4                             4          4
Product5                             3          2
```

I feel like this is standard excel work, so I'm sorry for the newbie ask here.  I have about 2000 records to go through on this, so I really don't want to do this manually.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want this in Excel? Why did you tag `google-sheets`?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the worksheets and create a Pivot table to you desired layout.

```
Sub CombineWS()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(before:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1))
    curRow = 2
    ws.Cells(1, 1) = "Month"
    ws.Cells(1, 2) = "Product Name"
    ws.Cells(1, 3) = "Total Items"
    ws.Cells(1, 4) = "Total Orders"
    With ws
        For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If sht.Name <> ws.Name Then
                Set rng = sht.Cells(2, 1).Resize(sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1, 3)

                rng.Copy
                ws.Cells(curRow, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                ws.Cells(curRow, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats

                ws.Cells(curRow, 1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count) = sht.Name

                curRow = curRow + rng.Rows.Count
            End If
        Next sht
    End With
End Sub
```